# Thread.sleep activates before previoues code

Tags: multithreading, threadpool

This code will check if three buttons in a row have the same text. If it does, it will change color to green on those buttons and change int counter to 9. When it is past this piece of code, it will reset all buttons their original state because counter == 9.

Problem is, it will sleep before it makes the buttons green. Why is that?

```
int counter = 0;

private void winCheck(String sign)
{
    if (jButton1.getText().equals(sign))
    {
        if (jButton2.getText().equals(sign))
        {
            if (jButton3.getText().equals(sign))
            {
                jButton1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                jButton2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                jButton3.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                counter = 9;   
            }

            try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } 
            catch(InterruptedException ex) 
                {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
        }
}

// This last part to show what I mean with reset.
counter++;

    if (counter == 10)
    {
        jButton1.setBackground(null);
        jButton1.setText(" ");

        counter = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Are you calling this inside some GUI event loop?

Comment: "Problem is, it will sleep before it makes the buttons green" - that is unlikely to be true. Step through your code - I bet that the button background colour value will be exactly what you expect it to be right after you set it (and before you hit `Thread.sleep`). You just can't *see* the update because your UI thread is busy waiting on the blocking `Thread.sleep` call to finish and not pumping. You either need an asynchronous alternative to `sleep` (timer for example) or a way to force the UI element to redraw immediately.

Comment: I set the colour to be green but it is not drawn before I put the thread to sleep?

Comment: @uranibaba, correct. And that's by design. The UI thread redraws the UI when it has nothing else to do. `Thread.sleep` does not defer the rest of the method - it *blocks* the thread so that it can't do anything else (i.e. redraw the UI) until the synchronous work is complete.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation! Is there away to mark your reply as a correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer by Kirill Shlenskiy (please upvote his comments):

Problem is, it will sleep before it makes the buttons green" - that is unlikely to be true. Step through your code - I bet that the button background colour value will be exactly what you expect it to be right after you set it (and before you hit Thread.sleep). You just can't see the update because your UI thread is busy waiting on the blocking Thread.sleep call to finish and not pumping. You either need an asynchronous alternative to sleep (timer for example) or a way to force the UI element to redraw immediately. –  Kirill Shlenskiy Jul 10 at 13:38

I set the colour to be green but it is not drawn before I put the thread to sleep? –  uranibaba Jul 11 at 8:10

@uranibaba, correct. And that's by design. The UI thread redraws the UI when it has nothing else to do. Thread.sleep does not defer the rest of the method - it blocks the thread so that it can't do anything else (i.e. redraw the UI) until the synchronous work is complete. –  Kirill Shlenskiy Jul 11 at 10:43